# Can I initialize string with NULLs in C

Tags: c, string

I have an 128x64px display. Current picture on display is saved in

```
uint8_t bufferOLED[(HEIGHT * WIDTH / 8)+1]; // uint8_t bufferOLED[1025];
```

If I load bufferOLED with strcpy and print to display everything works fine.

Now I want to initialize bufferOLED with some logo that will show up when booting application.

```
uint8_t bufferOLED[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //0
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //1
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //2
  ...
  0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, //49
  0x09, 0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, //50
  ...
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //100
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //101
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00                                      //102
}
```

Logo prints OK, but after I load bufferOLED with different content and print to display, image on display gets corrupted.

When writing to display I'm just sending bufferOLED with some commands to OLED:

```
for(int i=0; i<1024; i+=16) twiPrint(OLED, 0x40, bufferOLED+i, 16); //twiPrint(uint8_t twiAddress, uint8_t twiCommand, uint8_t *twiTransmitData, uint8_t twiTransmitDataLen)
```

I know that NULL character is used for terminating string. So is initialization with mix of NULL and not NULL characters allowed?

Comment: `I know that NULL character is used for terminating string`...no, it's either `NUL` or `null character`.

Comment: Don't you want to use memcpy instead ?

Comment: `"is initialization with mix of NULL and not NULL characters allowed?"` Of course, but you cannot consider the result a "string" (otherwise it would end at the first "*nul-character*" (not NULL character -- `NULL` is a *pointer*)). Your initialization is fine. The initialization could end after the line beginning `0x09` as the remaining elements would be initialized zero by default.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you. So Problem lays somewhere else.

Comment: Yep, if the compiler isn't warning about the initialization itself, then it is fine. I would look at any variables declared immediately before or after `bufferOLED` and make sure you are not writing beyond the limits with them, as that would likely corrupt what was initially in `bufferOLED`.